# Extracting from attribute tables by arcpy

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm having some trouble connecting ideas on how to solve a problem. What I have is a shapefile from which I have to extract from one field, which contains 3 types of attributes (BS, RS, BRN). For each of those attributes, I've created separate feature classes.

I short, attributes have to go to their specific designation e.g. BS values go to feature BS, RS values etc.

My first guess is that I have to use Cursors to do it, but in this case I have to use both Search and Insert and how would I do that?

Would it make sense a start such as this?

```
import arcpy

shape = "D:/M1 Geomatique/Programmation II/Dossier/ZONE_INONDATION_SYNTHESE_67.shp"
gdb = "D:/M1 Geomatique/Programmation II/Dossier/inondation.gdb"
field = "CODE_DEGRE" #field name from which to search data
entite1 = "rs"
entite2 = "bs"
entite3 = "brn"

rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(gdb)
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(shape)
```

Perform a loop start with a SearchCursor followed by an InsertCursor:
e.g.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sourceFC,fieldnames) as sCur:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(targetFC,fieldnames) as iCur:
```

Above is just an example I've picked up on stackexchange

How would you advise me to tackle this problem?

Comment: Could you use an if-else statement after the SearchCursor? Depending on what entite1 is based on the SearchCursor, InsertCursor will point toward a different feature class.

Comment: This is not python solution, but a solution may be the [Split tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000006000000.htm). Use the same features for input and split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cursors are great, but you don't need them for this operation.  Check out the [Make Feature Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000) tool, specifically the where_clause argument.  You can make a feature layer that only contains the "rs" features, and then use Copy Features to place it in the new location.

Alternatively, you could make a feature layer without using the where_clause (which would include all of the features), and then make three separate [Select Layer By Attribute](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000071000000) operations to get the subsets you want.  Once a selection is made, only those records will be copied with the Copy Features tool.

Finally, the [Select](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000005000000) tool will make a selection and output the features in a single step.  This would be the way to do it with the least code.  However, Feature Layers are a good thing to get used to using so I don't think you'd be wasting your time at all by pursuing the other methods.

Comment: That's an interesting proposition, I'll look into it and come back with a comment. Indeed, perhaps I should extend my vision towards other tools as well.

Comment: Is it entirely possible with cursors as well, and that would be a good way to go if you wanted to alter the cell values in any way, but I think you'll find these methods a little faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, they are quicker to make, easier to use, the code looks nice and clean, nothing really that could break if you added some additional functionality. I haven't tried the last one yet but will make sure that I do.